# No sound on Ubuntu after plugging in HDMI but aplay works and system sound works

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, 18.04

Fresh install of 18.04 after completely purging 16.04.

Aplay plays audio. Sound test in sound settings works. system sounds work
but browser sound and vlc/video player gives no sound output.

It was working till just before I plugged in hdmi to play on tv

Comment: Check/change volume with `alsamixer` on a terminal, move with the LEFT/RIGHT arrow keys to select an item, and increase the volume on every item with the UP arrow key.

Comment: @bistoco I found a way to get it working on VLC player i.e. by changing the default output source in audio settings to speakers/headphones. But I still cant get it to work on browser. I have tried the pacmd command to set output source

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to walk through [Sound troubleshooting procedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure) . I'd try step 6 first. Install `pavucontrol` and look maybe you have some applications muted. Also try changing audio device back and forth.

Answer (score 3):

Okay so this is how i solved it :

under the

```
~/.config/pulse/
```

there happened to be multiple config files. I just moved the ones concerning the HDMI to a new folder within the directory, killall pulse and then reboot.

It is working now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a full solution but here's a VERY strange solution that partially worked for me. Maybe this will help someone track down a full fix.

I'm assuming that you have an hdmi/displayport output as well as a headphone output.

1. Switch audio output to working headphone output (mine happens to work)
2. Play audio.
3. Use `aplay` to play something: (Something like `aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav`)
4. WHILE this is playing, switch to the not working HDMI output

This fixes it for me until audio stops playing, at which point it stops working again and this process needs to be repeated.